# Populate jQuery Mobile page content when a dynamic link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jquery-mobile

I'm kind of new to jQuery Mobile and AJAX requests. I'll try to be as clear as I can.

I'm developing a project for mobile and I'm using the jQuery Mobile auto-complete list, and populating it with an XML file (because it's too complicated for me to do it with a MySQL database right now).

I've succeeded in pulling the auto-complete list, filled with data from my external XML file (lista.xml), with this code:

```
<script>
$(function(){

$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "lista.xml",
 dataType: "xml",
 success: function(xml) {

  $(xml).find("anuro").each(function(){

  Cientifico = $(this).find("n_cientifico").text();
  Comun = $(this).find("n_comun").text();
  Foto = $(this).find("foto").text();
  Familia = $(this).find("familia").text();
  SubFamilia = $(this).find("subfamilia").text();

  $("#lista").append('<li><a href="#resultados" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/'+Foto+'"><h2>' + Cientifico + '</h2><p><b>Familia:</b> <i>'+Familia+'</i> | <b>Subfamilia:</b> <i>'+SubFamilia+'</i></p></a></li>');
  });
  $("#lista").listview("refresh");
 }
});
 });
 </script>
```

This is the code in the content part of my page:

```
<ul id="lista" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Buscar..." data-inset="true">
</ul>
```

This works fine right now. It loads all the data from my XML file, displays the correct picture of the anuro (frog) and the family, and all. My question is:
**How can I find out which option of the list is clicked, and populate another page `<div>` with the correct data from the same XML file?**
The idea of the web app is, as a user you search for an anuro (frog) by the scientific name, or by the family of the species, and when you click it the page displays more info about that species.

For another example, I'll paste a sample of what I want to accomplish, filled with sample data:

```
<!-- PAGINA RESULTADO -->   
    <div data-role="page" id="resultados">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>eFrogs</h1>
        <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">volver</a>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        <!-- TITULO -->
        <h3><center><i>Phyllomedusa Sauvagii</i></center></h3>

        <!-- FOTO -->
        <a href="#foto" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
        <img class="popphoto" style="margin-right:10px" src="img/phyllomedusa_sauvagii.jpg" alt="Phyllomedusa Sauvagii" width="100%"></a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="foto" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-corners="false">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
        Cerrar
        </a>
        <img class="popphoto" src="img/phyllomedusa_sauvagii.jpg" style="max-height:512px;" alt="Phyllomedusa Sauvagii">
        </div>  

    <br><br>

        <!-- GRILLA DE DATOS -->
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: right;">
                    Nombre Común
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar">
                    Rana Mono
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: right;">
                    Familia
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar">
                    Hyllidae
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: right;">
                    SubFamilia
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar">
                    Phyllomedusinae
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: right;">
                    Estado de Conservación
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="ui-bar">
                    Least Concern
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- DATOS EXTRA -->
        <h4 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">Distribución Geográfica</h4>
            <div class="ui-body">
                <p>Chacoan region of eastern Bolivia, northern Paraguay, Mato Grosso do Sul (Brazil), and northern Argentina.</p>
                <p>Up to 1500 m</p>
            </div>
        <h4 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">Hábitat y Ecología</h4>
            <div class="ui-body">
                <p>It occurs in the dry Chaco and is an arboreal species. It occurs on vegetation near temporary lagoons or ponds and the males call at night. They make a coarse leaf nest, filled with their glutinous egg-clutches which hangs over the water, the hatched tadpoles then drop in to the water below where they develop. It breeds only in the rainy season and is not tolerant of substantial habitat disturbance.</p>
            </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <!-- PIE DE PAGINA -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Webapp en Construcción</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page above it's filled with sample data. The idea it's that when you select an option, the data is updated with the correct one.
I hope you can understand all of this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood everything, but you could listen for the 'click' event on your list item :

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#phyllomedusa_sauvagii");
});
```

**EDIT :**

when you generate an item in your list, you can give it an id to retrive it easly:

```
<li id="anuro">...</li>
```

then you can add the event listener :

```
$('#anuro').on('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#phyllomedusa_sauvagii");
});
```

in your case, the code could look like this :

```
var item = ('<li id="aruno"><img src="img/'+Foto+'"><h2>' + Cientifico + '</h2><p><b>Familia:</b> <i>'+Familia+'</i> | <b>Subfamilia:</b> <i>'+SubFamilia+'</i></p></li>');
$('#lista').append(item);

item.on('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#phyllomedusa_sauvagii");
});

$("#lista").listview("refresh");
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Once you start understanding jquery, everything becomes easy.
below i edited part of the code a created above to replace the photo in your page :

```
item.on('click', function() {
    $('.popphoto').attr('src', 'img/'+Foto);
});
```

Comment: you might have an issue with your `<a>` element though... you'll probably need to remove it.

Comment: That's for knowing wich option is pressed, right? But how can I change the data so it be filled with the correspond data in the XML?

Comment: The #phyllomedusa_sauvagii it's an example page. The idea is when you click an option, all the data of that page updates with correspond data. For example, when you select FROG1 the page loads a FROG1 text in the header, load the correspondent image of that frog, etc. The only thing that it's the same are the desing of that page... I don't know if now is more clear...

Comment: look at my edited answer (there is a second 'edit'), don't forget to mark the question as resolved if it helped ! thank you :D

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but it's not what i'm looking for. I need help with the code to populate a page with correspondent data selected by a user. I can't explain it better, my english is too poor. The idea is that when you select a frog (example FROG1) the link takes me to another page (accomplished by multipages on jquery mobile) but that page is populated with the data of the FROG1. I click in the back button, and select the FROG2, then again the link take me to the SAME PAGE before, but now with FROG2 data. Hope this explains better :)

Comment: the second edit i made on my answer sould help you achieve this. it will update all elements with the class '.popphoto' with the proper 'Foto' as source

Comment: Thanks for the second edit. I've tested and works, but only the change is for the last item of my XML list... Another thing it's when I press the back button (that i've put in the header of the second page) the data doesn't change...

Comment: since you are updating pages instead of using different html pages, the back button won't undo the last ajax call. if you want to clear the content of your list or navigate to another page you have to do it using a button in your web page